# Titles of a playlist in YouTube

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

How to get the titles of all videos in a playlist (either through a program or any other means) in order to sort it offline?  I need this to put a vote among friends to sort it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest program I can think of to accomplish that would be the FireFox extension [BYTubeD](http://msram.github.io/bytubed/). With it, you can browse to the playlist, and just run it, and it will collect all the videos neatly like this:

[image: screen shot]

(Don't ask, I just found a random playlist).

Then you can copy and format as you wish.

Comment: BYTubeD has been discontinued, according to the home page.