# List all titles in order on a YouTube playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I have downloaded some YouTube videos in a playlist for offline viewing that have no indication of play order. I would like to know what the best means of listing the videos - in order - is so I can organise them locally?

The existing [answer to this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33678/titles-of-a-playlist-in-youtube) is outdated.

Comment: Looking at the playlist on YouTube doesn't work?

Comment: sometimes the list is very long and it would be nice to have a manifest rather than rely on the scrollable list on the side of the video player. it can become wieldy to keep track of where you are.

Comment: Do you want a separate file which contains the list of videos in order, or have the downloaded videos be named in the playlist order, or something else?

Comment: seperate file or a list online. not fussed. the important thing is it is a list of videos in the order in the playlist.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) for this, and specify the `playlist_index` tag in the output template.

For example:

`youtube-dl -o "%(playlist_index)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y064kgSr0gc&list=RDy064kgSr0gc"`

will download all the videos in this playlist and add the index number in the order of the playlist, padded with zeroes to accommodate the length of the playlist.

The `-o` flag specifies the output template.

Other useful flags for playlists are:

> ```
> --playlist-start NUMBER          Playlist video to start at (default is 1)
>
> --playlist-end NUMBER            Playlist video to end at (default is last)
>
> --playlist-items ITEM_SPEC       Playlist video items to download. Specify
>                                  indices of the videos in the playlist
>                                  separated by commas like: "--playlist-items
>                                  1,2,5,8" if you want to download videos
>                                  indexed 1, 2, 5, 8 in the playlist. You can
>                                  specify range: "--playlist-items
>                                  1-3,7,10-13", it will download the videos
>                                  at index 1, 2, 3, 7, 10, 11, 12 and 13.
> ```

There is also an `autonumber` tag for use in the output template, which inserts a 5 digit number, in the order downloaded.